# Caption/label methods don't work

Tags: python, minimagick

I'm trying to write multiline text on my image using caption and/or label, but it doesn't write anything to the image.

```
def self.post_open_ended_response
  image = MiniMagick::Image.open("public/text_response_bg.png")
  image.combine_options do |i|
    i.size "460x"
    i.gravity 'center'
    i.fill 'white'
    i.pointsize '40'
    i.caption 'blahblahblah'
    # i.label "blahblah  fsdfsd fsd fsd fds fsd fds fds"
    # i.composite "public/output.jpg"
 end
 image.write "public/output.jpg"
end
```

The reason I want to use caption/label instead of text is because I read that imagemagick will magically scale the pointsize for caption/label. My text length will vary, so I don't want to hardcode it.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue in the meantime? Facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who may faces the issue in future - update to the latest gem (at the moment 4.2.0). I was on 4.0.4 and had the issue:

https://github.com/minimagick/minimagick/issues/191

Update - in general simply use annotate - it works. If you require text manipulation you can do so with TextHelpers. I have done the following as example for multiline annotation:

```
def create_og_image
  message = word_wrap('This is a test string. ' + @blog.title, line_width: 30).upcase

  image = MiniMagick::Image.open(@blog.image.path(:open_graph))
  image.combine_options do |c|
    #c.label message
    c.gravity 'NorthWest'
    c.fill 'white'
    c.stroke 'white'
    c.strokewidth '0'
    c.pointsize '70'
    c.interline_spacing '10'
    c.font "AvantGarde-Book"
    #c.size "500x300 label:'#{message}'"
    #c.label message
    c.annotate '+500+318', message

  end

  image.write "/xxx/xxx/xxx/public/test_image/test_output.jpg"
end
```